# Temporary favorites

Tags: discussion, bookmarks

I tend to mark things as "favorite" more as a bookmark than anything else.

However, sometimes I go back through them and realize that there are those I just don't care about anymore and I hate clutter.  Obviously unmarking them as a favorite is the answer.  Then again, I feel bad about "unfavoriting" something because I know the OP is going to lose the points I had originally given.

How about if someone unfavorites an item, instead of taking those points back, just let them have it.  After it was a favorite for awhile.. just not forever.

Comment: Favoriting and rep are independent, so un-fave away.

Answer (score 11):

The OP does not lose reputation points when you unfavorite a post, nor does he gain reputation points when you favorite it.

There might be some badges that are dependent on the favorites, but the OP won't lose badges if your unfavorite drops them below the badge threshold.

So feel free to unfavorite posts guilt-free.